# How to find out where is being redirected and which controller is handling data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this form (Only showing the essential parts):

```
<form id="formservicos" method="POST" action="#" class="special-contact-form">
<input type="button" id="sendServicos" value="Enviar" class="btn v-btn v-third-dark submit-contact">
```

Then I have this JavaScript:

```
$("#sendServicos").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var agree = $('#agree_1');

        if( agree.is(':checked')) {
            var form = $("#formservicos");
            var data = form.serialize();
            
            $.post( form.attr('action'), data, function (r) {
                if (!r.success) {
                    $('#formservicos .alert-danger').text(r.message);
                    $('#formservicos .alert-danger').removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $('#formservicos .alert-success').removeClass('hidden');
                    form.closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#formservicos .alert').addClass('hidden');
                }, 5000);

                grecaptcha.reset();
            });
        }else{
            alert('Tem de concordar com o envio dos seus dados pessoais');
        }
    });
```

How can I find out which controller is handling this data?

Comment: you should specify a route in your ajax and there is no routing in your whole script

Comment: @AmirJani If I dump in the console the 'r' of the function I get this: {success: false, message: "Trying to get property of non-object"}

Comment: @RicardoBarbosa It sends a request for the same link that you are currently on in the browser bar

Answer (score 1):

if action didn't specified. It post all data to the current page. This page (get) is in the route file so add post next to it.
For example you are opening this page with:

```
Route::get('/form', 'FormController@index');
```

then add `Route::post('/form', 'FormController@index');`

Comment: The routes are in this way:

// Load user pages
Route::group(['middleware' => ['visit']], function () {

    // Display content
    Route::any('/{slug?}', 'SiteController@showContent');
    
});

Comment: Route::post('/form', 'FormController@index'); change to Route::post('/form', 'FormController@post'); create a post method in your FormController and try some logging in that controller.    you can also, Route::post('/form', 'FormController@index')->name('myformpost'); and use <form id="formservicos" method="POST" action="{{route('myformpost')}}" class="special-contact-form"> as the action.   otherwise your index method is trying to handle both "showing the form" and "processing the form post"

Comment: Yes, @Cameron was right. This is the right way to do it. 

But if you are using Route::any(...), my answer is perfectly fit for you. You should handle the post in the same function. This isn't the very perfect answer but it works.